# how to suspend activity for the result of a dialogbox

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I've an app that tests whether a variable is null or not. If it is null the i show a dialog box that sets the variable. The problem is that the activity continues to execute whilest the box is showing. I'd like my activity to hang and wait for the result of the dialogbox then resume. How can i acheive this?

```
if(nfcscannerapplication.getCompId() == null || 
                                   nfcscannerapplication.getCompId().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("null")){ 
            Log.e(TAG, "compid null***********");
            showPasswordDialogBox();



        }else{

            Log.e(TAG, "compid not null***********");
            String[] paramsCompOpt = new String[]{nfcscannerapplication.getCompId()};
            AsyncGetCompanyOptions agco = new AsyncGetCompanyOptions();
            agco.execute(paramsCompOpt);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
 preMethod() {
        // Your actual code...
        if(nfcscannerapplication.getCompId() == null || nfcscannerapplication.getCompId().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("null")){ 
                    Log.e(TAG, "compid null***********");


                // Call postMethod() once the variable is set in the Dialog box**
                showPasswordDialogBox();

            } else{

                Log.e(TAG, "compid not null***********");
                String[] paramsCompOpt = new String[]{nfcscannerapplication.getCompId()};
                AsyncGetCompanyOptions agco = new AsyncGetCompanyOptions();
                agco.execute(paramsCompOpt);

                postMethod();    
            }
}

postMethod() {
  // Code to execute when the variable is set
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the code that requires the variable to be set in a private method. Then if the variable is properly initialized you call that method. Or if it is not properly initialized you show the dialog and call the private method in the on close handler.